# Implement a priority queue using only ONE stack

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Implementing a queue or a priority queue using **two stacks** are not hard.

Now the questions are

1. How about using **only ONE stack** to implement a **priority** queue?
2. How about using **only ONE stack** to implement a **normal** queue?

Are they even possible?

p.s. of course you should use `constant` extra space other than ONE stack if necessary

Comment: Possible, most likely. Inefficient? Definitely.

Comment: @AlejandroLucena Performance is not a matter here. but is it really possible? only one stack with at most constant space?

Comment: As long as you keep mechanics for stack (can only delete first item), I think there is no way to simulate queue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible using only methods provided through a stack interface (i.e. using only push and pop methods) with constant extra space. <sup>[1]</sup>

Consider trying to simulate a queue using a stack.

When enqueueing, if we simply push onto the stack, we'll end up with another element we need to do something with to get to the front of the queue for a dequeue. It's easy to see that a bunch of enqueues will make it impossible for the next dequeue to take a constant amount of space, as all these enqueued elements need to be popped to get to the front of the queue. We could also put the enqueued element a constant number of elements from the top of the stack, but this doesn't really help much either - the elements below it will need to be dequeued first, so we run into the same problem. Trying to put the enqueued element further than a constant number of elements from the top of the stack will of course take more than a constant amount of space already.

Now consider a priority queue where each new item has lower priority than all items already in the queue. This is synonymous to a simply queue, which, from the above argument, can't be simulated using a single stack with constant space.

[1]: If the stack was implemented as an array or linked-list, as it typically is, it would of course be possible using the functionality for those, but I'm sure that's not what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Say you push `n` elements onto your stack. Now you want the element at the bottom of it (if you want to implement a queue). You're going to need extra O(n) space to keep your other `n-1` elements so you can access the bottom one.

=> Under your constraints and only the stack interface methods, there's no way you're going to implement a queue using a *single* stack and *constant* space.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to perform the task if you only allow standard stack operations (`pop`, `push`), as queueing an item would mean poping all the items from the stack, pushing the new item, and then push back all the items. If you use constant time, you can't pop all the items and keep track of them with `O(1)` memory.

Let's assume you implement a stack with a two-way linked list and allow a `reverse` method- meaning you flip the order of the stack (tail of the linked list becomes the tail).

Now, for a regular queue, you can perform:

`queue`- perform `reverse`, `push` the new item, and `reverse` again.
`dequeue`- perform `pop`.

Note once you allow a `reverse` action, it's not a standard stack anymore.

A priority queue is still impossible impossible to implement even if you allow `reverse`, as you'll still have to perform various comparisons when queueing or dequeueing, and will still encounter the problem of having no space to store the items you want to compare.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that is technically correct, but almost certainly useless for your purposes.

We use a stack `S` of queues (regular or priority). We initialise `S` to hold a single empty queue. For any queue operation, we peek at the top element of `S` and apply the queue operation to it in place. This way, `S` will only ever hold a single element.

This uses zero memory outside of the stack, if you take the viewpoint that the stack "owns" the memory of all its elements.